# \mathrm and \Omega in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex

When I write `$\mathrm{\Omega}$` and compile it with LaTeX, I get capital omega symbol normally. But when I do the same with XeLaTeX, I get empty symbol. I don't use any special packages or fonts.

Could someone explain me why is this? And how could I achieve the same behavior in XeLaTeX as in LaTeX?

Example of LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Article}
\author{Name}
\date{}
\begin{document}
   $\text{nothing:} \Omega +  \text{rm} \mathrm{\Omega} + \text{normal} \mathnormal{\Omega}$
\end{document}
```

Example of XeLaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\title{Article}
\author{Name}
\date{}
\begin{document}
   $\text{nothing:} \Omega +  \text{rm} \mathrm{\Omega} + \text{normal} \mathnormal{\Omega}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: the Omega is _always_ upright so `\mathrm` makes no sense. However, make a complete example, that shows your seen behaviour. I have no problem with `xelatex`

Comment: What math font do you load in the xelatex variant of your code?

Comment: Does XeLaTeX produce any warnings when you compile your document? If so, add those warnings (contained in the `.log` file) to your question by `edit`ing it.

Comment: It maybe a good idea, if you could test your example before posting it. `amsmath` is missing and as I already wrote, load `mathspec` instead of `fontspec`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\Omega` for upright Ω, and use `\varOmega` with `amsmath` package for italic *Ω*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

$\Omega \varOmega$

\end{document}
```

---

Some more explanations:

With `fontspec`, `\mathrm` uses text roman fonts by default. However, there is no Ω in Latin Modern Roman font, thus the symbol is missing.

Sometimes, you may want to use `no-math` option of `fontspec` to prevent changing the math fonts, if you use some math font packages. However, you should just use correct way to typeset `\Omega` and `\varOmega` instead.

Comment: loading `mathspec` instead of `fontspec` makes `\mathrm{\Omega}` work

Comment: Finally, I used the `no-math` option when loading `fontspec` package. Should I expect any "side-effects"?

Comment: @Werkov: You should not use `\mathrm{\Omega}`. Then `no-math` option is useless.